# How to disable PendSV in Cortex-M0?

Tags: exception, arm, cortex-m

I have a simple and stupid question , Can i disable PendSV exception in Cortex-M0 architectures by writing to `ICER` register?

As 'Cortex-M0 Devices Generic User Guide' says :

> Privileged software can disable the exceptions that Table 2-11 on page 2-20 shows as
>   having configurable priority, see Interrupt Clear-enable Register on page 4-5.

it can be done in privileged mode.

[image: Table 2-11 on page 2-20]

But in my code , Although i disabled PendSV_IRQn by `NVIC_DisableIRQ(PendSV_IRQn)` , PendSV exception (`PendSV_Handler` ISR)  occurs by executing `SCB->ICSR |= SCB_ICSR_PENDSVSET` yet!  ( I'm sure MCU is in privilaged mode [`CONTROL` = 0]). Where is my fault?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Other ARM architectures support the concept of privileged or unprivileged software
execution. This processor does not support different privilege levels. Software
execution is always privileged, meaning software can access all the features of the
processor.

Comment: I tend to avoid the documents other than the architectural reference manual, the technical reference manual and on occasion the amba/axi/ahb manuals.  the programmers manuals like this one tend to have as many problems as solutions.  first time I looked at one of these additional documents found big problems and looked away.  There has been a rare occasion or two where one of these documents has something the ARM or TRM doesnt have, always cross reference anything you find and want to use with the ARM and TRM.

Comment: Thank you @old_timer. it seems 'Cortex-M0 Devices Generic User Guide' is not too exact.

Comment: assume all documents are buggy, because they generally are, sometimes just typos sometimes bigger problems.  but go with that assumption and as a result have do your own hacking/testing to confirm the documentation and you will overall be better off.

Comment: and then sometimes you end up where you ended up here, it doesnt seem to make sense what is going

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ARMv6-M Architecture Reference Manual says (in Section B1.5.1 "Overview of the exceptions supported"):

> PendSV is permanently enabled,...

This would appear to contradict your quote, so one of them must be wrong. Your experiment suggests that the Cortex-M0 Devices Generic User Guide is wrong here.